# C# - extract data from serialized chars

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm having diffulties with this. I am fetching an object and serializing it and it ends up looking like some kind of json, but it isn't. foreach (var t in tester) just ends up printing every char.

```
var info = await client.GetAccountInformation();

            var tester = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(info);
            Console.WriteLine(tester);
          foreach (var t in tester)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(t);
               //t is a char
            }
```

Actual data looks like this:

```
{  
   "MakerCommission":10,
   "TakerCommission":10,
   "BuyerCommission":0,
   "SellerCommission":0,
   "CanTrade":true,
   "CanWithdraw":true,
   "CanDeposit":true,
   "Balances":[  
      {  
         "Asset":"BTC",
         "Free":0.00000372,
         "Locked":0.00000000
      },
      {  
         "Asset":"LTC",
         "Free":0.00000000,
         "Locked":0.00000000
      },
```

Is there any way to get this {"Asset":"BTC","Free":0.00000372,"Locked":0.00000000} without looping through all the chars and comparing string?

Comment: Do you have a model with the properties? If you do, you can deserialize the information into a model.

Comment: Are you talking about a json class? I tried to convert the data from json c# but it didn't work.

Comment: He means creating a model with properties for each of the keys, then using `Newtonsoft.Json`'s `DeserializeObject` to deserialize into that

Comment: @Jaxi there is no need for an external lib, he also could use the JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize

Comment: @mr.void fair enough :)

Comment: I may misunderstand you but I think I tried to create a model with http://json2csharp.com/ but it says Parsing json didn't work.

Comment: What type is `info`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
var info = await client.GetAccountInformation();

foreach (var balance in info.Balances)
{
     var serializedBalanceObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(balance);
     Console.WriteLine(serializedBalanceObject.ToString());
}
```